# How to initialize a static readonly variable using an anonymous method?

Tags: c#, static, delegates, anonymous-function, static-members

I'm trying to clean up my code for initializing static readonly variables.

Original:

```
public static readonly List<int> MyList;

//Initialize MyList in the static constructor
static MyObject() { ... }
```

---

I decided to clean it up because CodeAnalysis said I should not use the static constructor (CA1810).

Cleanup:

```
public static readonly List<int> MyList = GetMyList();

//Returns the list
private static List<int> GetMyList() { ... }
```

---

I didn't really like the additional method, so I figured I'd try to get it to be all inline, but it won't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

```
public static readonly List<int> MyList =
    () =>
       {
           ...

           return list;
       };
```

I attempted to take the code within the `GetMyList()` method and place it in an anonymous delegate to return the list to assign, but it says I'm attempting to convert a `delegate` into a `List<int>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks a little weird, but try this:

```
public static readonly List<int> MyList = new Func<List<int>>(
() =>
{
    // Create your list here
    return new List<int>();
})();
```

The trick is creating a new `Func<List<int>>` and invoking it.

Comment: That is quite weird, perhaps it's best to keep it in a standard method then?

Comment: @michael Perhaps -- depends on what you think is more readable and maintainable. Are these values constant? Could you use `public static readonly List<int> MyList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };` ?

Comment: No, there's more to it than that, otherwise inlining it would be super easy.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that when you write

```
() =>
   {
       ...

       return list;
   };
```

You're actually declaring a delegate - a function that returns `List<int>`, but you're not actually invoking that function, and therefore this evaluates to `Func<List<int>>` and not to `List<int>`.

I'm not quite sure why you're trying to remove your static constructor though. Static constructors have their uses, and in some cases even make the code cleaner and more readable.

Comment: +1. Yes, to get result one needs to call function... also I prefer separate function for it.  "iffe" looks more natural in JavaScript :)

Answer (score 2):

> it says I'm attempting to convert a delegate into a `List<int>`

That's because you are. Remember that defining the lambda isn't the same as invoking the lambda. You'd have to be doing something more like this:

```
Func<List<int>> createList = () => { ... return list; };
MyList = createList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should immediately invoke it for it to become a list:

```
public static readonly List<int> MyList = new Func<List<int>>(() => {
    return new List<int>();
})(); //<-- the parentheses that invoke
```

The Syntax in C# for this is so iffy that it's probably best to go with separate invocation or method.

Answer (score 1):

It says right. `() => ...` returns a delegate. But you need a list. For that reason you must call this delegate and have result.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the parenthesis . Use this :

```
public static readonly List<int> MyList = (() =>
{
    ...
    return list;
});
```

Comment: CAUTION:  **Will not compile.** I upvoted this, after testing a different variation, in a different situation, where I actually *did* need a delegate, not an evaluation. Can't change my upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

As many have stated, plain `() => { ... }` returns a delegate or Expression. I think creating a separate `private static` method for the list initialization makes a slightly more readable code than `() => { ... }()` or `() => { ... }.Invoke()`

Comment: BTW, the alternative syntaxes you propose (but dismiss as less readable) do not compile. (I recommend deleting this answer.)